# Un-Escaping XML encoded characters

Tags: php, xml, htmlspecialchars, xml-entities

Hi I got response as like instead of STD xml. How Can i convert it into XML by using PHP ..

```
    &lt;&#x3f;xml&#x20;version&#x3d;&#x22;1.0&#x22;&#x20;encoding&#x3d;&#x22;UTF-8&#x22;&#x3f;&gt;&lt;SOAP-ENV&#x3a;Envelope&#x20;xmlns&#x3a;SOAP-ENC&#x3d;&#x22;http&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;schemas.xmlsoap.org&#x2f;soap&#x2f;encoding&#x2f;&#x22;&#x20;xmlns&#x3a;SOAP-ENV&#x3d;&#x22;http&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;schemas.xmlsoap.org&#x2f;soap&#x2f;envelope&#x2f;&#x22;&gt;&lt;SOAP-ENV&#x3a;Body&gt;&lt;rfc&#x3a;ZHR_TIMESHEETS_GETLIST.Response&#x20;xmlns&#x3a;rfc&#x3d;&#x22;urn&#x3a;sap-com&#x3a;document&#x3a;sap&#x3a;rfc&#x3a;functions&#x22;&gt;&lt;ZDAYSUMMARY&gt;&lt;&#x2f;ZDAYSUMMARY&gt;&lt;ZMESSAGES&gt;&lt;item&gt;&lt;MANDT&gt;&lt;&#x2f;MANDT&gt;&lt;PERNR&gt;00956025&lt;&#x2f;PERNR&gt;&lt;WKSTRTDT&gt;0000-00-00&lt;&#x2f;WKSTRTDT&gt;&lt;WKENDDT&gt;0000-00-00&lt;&#x2f;WKENDDT&gt;&lt;ZDAY&gt;0&lt;&#x2f;ZDAY&gt;&lt;ZMESSAGE&gt;E&lt;&#x2f;ZMESSAGE&gt;&lt;ZCOLOR_CODE&gt;&lt;&#x2f;ZCOLOR_CODE&gt;&lt;ZMESSAGE_T&gt;You&#x20;have&#x20;no&#x20;reportees.&lt;&#x2f;ZMESSAGE_T&gt;&lt;&#x2f;item&gt;&lt;&#x2f;ZMESSAGES&gt;&lt;ZTSDETAIL&gt;&lt;&#x2f;ZTSDETAIL&gt;&lt;ZWKSUMMARY&gt;&lt;&#x2f;ZWKSUMMARY&gt;&lt;&#x2f;rfc&#x3a;ZHR_TIMESHEETS_GETLIST.Response&gt;&lt;&#x2f;SOAP-ENV&#x3a;Body&gt;&lt;&#x2f;SOAP-ENV&#x3a;Envelope&gt;
```

Thanks,
Mangesh

Comment: would you mind sharing how do you get this response in the first place? maybe it would be easier to get the XML in the first place(if possible) instead of getting this and try and convert it back to xml.

Comment: looks like a http response.

Comment: nah, it's actually SOAP, which, if handle properly, should be handled by SOAP client no problem. Still need to take a look at his code thou

Comment: No I dont have control over what I will get response..it is coming from SAP backend..

Comment: that's not what i meant, i mean the code you use to receive the message. did you simply do $_POST ? show it in the question if possible.

Comment: I have taken the code from log files. Simple function call. Earlier I use to get proper xml but now SAPbackend upgraded and response is coming like above..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
html_entity_decode("your_string")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the request headers, try using `Content-Type: application/soap+xml;`

If not, just use `html_entity_decode()` on the response string.